# How to save credentials of technical user in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

We have multiple PowerShell scripts which need the credentials of a technical user.

- What is a good way to store these credentials securely/hashed while keeping them available to each user having permission to run the script?

We tried hashing as secure string but this requires each user to hash the credentials, as the secure string is tied to the user's profile.

I was unsuccesful trying to implement something like this:

"run script as administrator -> click yes to dialog -> switch to tech user -> unhash credentials -> rehash as logged in user -> save to file"

(The users do have administrator priviliges)

I could have each user enter the credentials once and then save the user specific hash to a file. But I presume there is a best practice for doing this which I haven't found yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$username = "user1@domain.com"
$pwdTxt = Get-Content "C:\temp\Stored_Password.txt"
$securePwd = $pwdTxt | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePwd
# Now, $credObject is having the credentials stored and you can pass it wherever you want.


## Import Password with AES

$username = "user1@domain.com"
$AESKey = Get-Content $AESKeyFilePath
$pwdTxt = Get-Content $SecurePwdFilePath
$securePwd = $pwdTxt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $AESKey
$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePwd

# Now, $credObject is having the credentials stored with AES Key and you can pass it wherever you want.
```

---

You can put any key to encrypt the credentials and similarly you can decrypt. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Your AES example is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Lerkes: If the example helped  you , then you can upvote the example cause that will help others too.